# (AngularJS / ng-route) How to get inputs for the template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, ngroute, ng-view

I have an index.html file that uses ng-route to link to a new view (e.g. "index.html/Book/:BookId").

On the index.html file, I can see all the appropriate information about each item (say, each book). On index.js, I have a controller called routeCtrl, inside which there is a list, and each book object is an item in that list.

Problem: while I can link to the new ng-view, I can't figure out how to get the information for each page. For example, if I click on the "Macbeth" link in the first page, I should see the information of Macbeth in the new view.

Here's my code.

Index.html:

```
<html>
...
<body ng-app="routeApp" ng-controller="routeCtrl">
  <div ng-view></div>
  <div ng-repeat="book in books">
    <h1><a href="Book/{{ book.url }}">{{ book.name }}</a></h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js:

```
var app = angular.module('routeApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('routeCtrl, function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
  $scope.$location = $location;
  $scope.$route = $route;
  $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
  $scope.books = [
    Atlas Shrugged = { name: "Atlas Shrugged", author: "Ayn Rand", url: "atlas"},
    Neuromancer = { name: "Neuromancer", author: "William Gibson", url: "neuro"}
  ];
});

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/Book/:bookId', {
      templateUrl: 'book.html',
      controller: 'routeCtrl',
  })

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Book.html (which goes in the ng-view):

```
<div> // this is the part I don't understand. How do I retrieve each book's information from the object in the JS file?
  <h1>{{ BOOK NAME }}</h1>
  <h3>{{ BOOK AUTHOR }}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is $scope.books here? You would use that (books) in your HTML template but you can't really iterate over a list formatted like that.

try this instead:

```
$scope.books = [
  { name: "Atlas Shrugged", author: "Ayn Rand", url: "atlas"},
  { name: "Neuromancer", author: "William Gibson", url: "neuro"}
];
```

That would yield a "books" object in the template that you could ng-repeat="book in books" and access the properties in the ng-repeat block like {{book.name}} as you are doing above.

Comment: $scope.books is the list of books that will appear in index.html. Each book in the list has a link to an ng-view that should give more info on each book. If I use ng-repeat, I would be getting the info for ALL books, and I just want to get the info for the book the user clicked on. I'm very new to programming, so I might be totally wrong here, too.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I've noticed that the routeCtrl is used both in the app and inside the ng-view (via router). I'd probably try to use separate controllers for separate functionality. Then, assuming you don't initialize a new scope in the ng-view, you should be able to access the routeCtrl scope (ie, $scope.books) and look for the book with the passed id in there and attach it to scope.

Comment: Right, awesome. And now the noob part: how do I look for the book with the passed id and attach it to scope?

Comment: How do the IDs correspond to the data in $scope.books? Index of the array? if so: books[bookID].name, etc. bookID should be accessible from $routeParams['bookID']. You might need to parseInt on bookID (since it would be passed as a string)